# How to convert YYYYQ to YYYYMMDD in SQL

Tags: sql

I'd like to convert the format YYYYQ to YYYYMMDD, for example:

`20132` to `20130601`

I tried to do so using this formula: `concat(year,'0',quarter*3,'01') as Date`

However, an extra '0' will be added for all Q4's, for example the formula will turn 20144 to 201401201, but I want the output `20141201`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your example format suggests that you have one string, but the code suggests two columns.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1):

How about just using a `case`:

```
select (case when quarter = 1 then concat(year, '0101')
             when quarter = 2 then concat(year, '0401')
             when quarter = 3 then concat(year, '0701')
             when quarter = 4 then concat(year, '1001')
        end)
```

I'm not sure what logic you are using for quarters, but for the typical definition, they begin on Jan 1, Apr 1, Jul 1, and Oct 1.  This is easy to adjust for other definitions.